# Is it safe to store a public SSH rsa key in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, encryption, ssh

I could just encrypt the key even further and store that value in MongoDB, but is it just as safe storing the key in MongoDB? It's public information, so it's not too sensitive if someone were to go through the effort and try to hack my database.

I'm a noob in encryption and SSH, so I apologize if this question sounds completely stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be safe, if your mongoDB is not publicly available over the internet. This means that you and your services should be able to access the database, but no body else. MongoDB is "hackable" if the port is available on the public network.

There's no point in encrypting the public key, even if it's out, you'd need a private key to make use of it. (which is *usually* only usable by its owner).

Answer (score 2):

It's safe to store your public key anywhere.  There are no security ramifications.  The key is public in every sense of the word.